# What is the actual sequence of steps during rm -Rf on a very large folder?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rm, ext4

Let's say I run `rm -Rf` on a very large folder with many files and folders of different size, user permissions etc.

I would like to know, does the `rm` command first accumulate the list of files to delete and only after it scans the whole folder for these files it starts to delete?
or does it actually delete each file as soon as it hits during the command duration?

For example, imagine you run the `rm -Rf /` command and after 5 seconds you terminate it, will it delete anything meanwhile?

The fs on that particular mounted folder is `ext4`.

Comment: Run `strace` against it, find out ?

Comment: @steve can you give me an example ```strace``` command for a folder ```rm -Rf /data/*```

Comment: So if you specify `/data/*`, you're going to see the shell expand it first.  Assuming you've got files/dirs named 1 thru 3 in there, you'd see the `rm` command passed a line consisting of `rm -Rf /data/1 /data/2 /data/3` and so on.  `strace -fo /tmp/mylog rm -Rf /data/*`.  With `/tmp/mylog` you'll see the multiple calls to unlinkat / newfsatat, as it works its way through the list.

Comment: @steve seems like the ```strace``` command only lists the current call, not history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `rm -Rf /`, `rm` will output an error message and stop, as [specified by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html):

> if an operand resolves to the root directory, *rm* shall write a diagnostic message to standard error and do nothing more with such operands.

In other cases, or if you force `rm` to process `/` (assuming your version can be forced, *e.g.* GNU `rm` with the `--no-preserve-root` option), `rm` deletes files and directories as soon as it can. It processes directories in depth-first order, so that it can delete directories as they are emptied. So in your five seconds, it is likely to delete files and directories.

This is specified by POSIX (see the above link):

> For each *file* the following steps shall be taken:
>
> 1. If the *file* does not exist:
>
>    a. If the **-f** option is not specified, *rm* shall write a diagnostic message to standard error.
>
>    b. Go on to any remaining *files*.
> 2. If *file* is of type directory, the following steps shall be taken:
>
>    a. If neither the **-R** option nor the **-r** option is specified, *rm* shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, do nothing more with *file*, and go on to any remaining files.
>
>    b. If *file* is an empty directory, *rm* may skip to step 2d. If the **-f** option is not specified, and either the permissions of *file* do not permit writing and the standard input is a terminal or the **-i** option is specified, *rm* shall write a prompt to standard error and read a line from the standard input. If the response is not affirmative, *rm* shall do nothing more with the current file and go on to any remaining files.
>
>    c. For each entry contained in *file*, other than dot or dot-dot, the four steps listed here (1 to 4) shall be taken with the entry as if it were a *file* operand. The *rm* utility shall not traverse directories by following symbolic links into other parts of the hierarchy, but shall remove the links themselves.
>
>    d. If the **-i** option is specified, *rm* shall write a prompt to standard error and read a line from the standard input. If the response is not affirmative, *rm* shall do nothing more with the current file, and go on to any remaining files.
> 3. If *file* is not of type directory, the **-f** option is not specified, and either the permissions of file do not permit writing and the standard input is a terminal or the **-i** option is specified, *rm* shall write a prompt to the standard error and read a line from the standard input. If the response is not affirmative, *rm* shall do nothing more with the current file and go on to any remaining files.
> 4. If the current file is a directory, *rm* shall perform actions equivalent to the [*rmdir()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html) function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 called with a pathname of the current file used as the *path* argument. If the current file is not a directory, *rm* shall perform actions equivalent to the [*unlink()*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) function defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017 called with a pathname of the current file used as the *path* argument.
>
>    If this fails for any reason, *rm* shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, do nothing more with the current file, and go on to any remaining files.
>
> The *rm* utility shall be able to descend to arbitrary depths in a file hierarchy, and shall not fail due to path length limitations (unless an operand specified by the user exceeds system limitations).

Comment: Also note files are unlinked and might be recoverable unless shred/etc are used.