# Will `rm -rf` continue deleting if it can't delete something in the middle?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, rm, resources, failover

Consider a dir `garbage` containing many files and directories.
If I run `rm -rf garbage`, but some files or directories within `garbage` are busy by the OS/NFS/etc., so `rm -rf` will fail for them. Will it delete the rest? Or will it stop deleting upon the first failure?
The current OS is Ubuntu 20.04, but it's of interest whether this behavior is standard, or it depends on the (version of) OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rm`’s behaviour [is specified in detail in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) (see also [What is the actual sequence of steps during rm -Rf on a very large folder?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/486572/86440) which reproduces the full sequence). In all cases where it can’t remove the current file or it doesn't exist, it must

> go on to any remaining files

This means that even in case of failure, it will continue deleting files (if it can). This applies both to files specified as arguments to `rm -rf`, and to files found while processing directories.

Note that in some cases it will permanently wait for the result of an operation (*e.g.* if it tries to remove a file on an NFS mount whose server isn’t responding); it will end up in uninterruptible sleep (state `D`), but if that state ever resolves, it will continue deleting files. It never actually *stops* deleting until it’s run out of files to delete.

Answer (score 0):

`rm -r` essentially unlinks "file" entries, whether they're files, directories, symbolic links, etc. (e.g., using `unlinkat`), first iterating through any directories encountered (e.g., using `getdents`).  At no point does does `rm` attempt to open, read from, or write to files it encounters.  That said, if `rm` attempts a `getdents` on a directory that triggers a I/O wait uninterruptible sleep, `rm` will await the resolution of that wait to continue.

That said, if `rm` is unable to complete the `unlinkat`, exceptions are handled on a case-by-case basis.  For example, if the `unlinkat` fails because the file was missing, `rm` will continue, though will report the `ENOENT` (`No such file or directory`).

Comment: The question is about `rm -rf` which doesn't report ENOENT (or ENOTDIR in the case of `rm -rf /etc/passwd/foo` for instance) errors.

Comment: unlinking a file from a directory implies modifying that directory file obviously.